# CSS Sprits, Add Padding to Background Image

Tags: html, css, css-sprites

i'm new to css sprits. i have added a **small red color arrow like image** to all links in a DIV ID. it looks like this.(image attached)

how to get some padding after the background image ? i mean some space between image and text using CSS.

[image]

**CSS**

```
#maincontent a:link {
background: url(images/css-images.png) no-repeat top left;
background-position: 0 0;
width: 4px;
height: 12px;
display:inline;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="maincontent">
<a href="results/2013/31r09sup.php">Btech III</a>
</div>
```

**i tried adding to css *padding right*, but it is giving some space after text not after image.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use padding on your link, this will leave the background where it is but move the text, try `padding-left: 25px;`. But adding padding will add to the width so you will want to adjust the width of your link and reduce it by the amount of padding you have added (maybe not in this example)

Also your example image isn't loading

Try this:

```
#maincontent a:link {
background: url(images/css-images.png) no-repeat top left;
background-position: 0 0;
width: 4px;
padding-left: 25px;
height: 12px;
display:inline;
}
```

Comment: No problem, I also noticed your width is only `4px` if your adding text into the div, make sure to remove the width so it will adjust itself.

Comment: simin, stackoverflow asking me to wait 2 more min to select a answer :( mean time i have another problem. http://awesomescreenshot.com/0401nvcn0f see this image. how to get the image to show to center.. used the same css. but removed width and changed background to `url("images/new.gif") no-repeat scroll 0% 0% transparent !important`

Comment: you want to add position center then left, something like: `background: url ("images/new.gif") no-repeat left center;`

Answer (score 0):

just apply a `padding-left` or a `text-indent` to your link